# Creating conditional (changing) name in a list() in R

Tags: r, list, function

I was wondering if there might be a way to create a *conditional name* in an R `list()`?

For example, below if `blue = TRUE`, I want my list to output `Nov. = 1 2 3 4` but when `blue = FALSE` I want my list to output `Sep. = 1 2 3 4`.

Here is what I tried (with no success):

```
bar <- function(blue = TRUE){

list(if(blue) "Nov." else "Sep." = 1:4)
}
# Example of use:
bar()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might be the best option:

```
bar <- function(blue=TRUE) {
    x <- list(1:4)
    setNames(x, ifelse(blue, "Nov.", "Sep."))
}

bar()
## $`Nov.`
## [1] 1 2 3 4

bar(FALSE)
## $`Sep.`
## [1] 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

with `tibble::lst` and `rlang` you can actually write this :

```
library(tibble)
library(rlang)
bar <- function(blue = TRUE){
  lst(!! (if(blue) "Nov." else "Sep.") := 1:4)
}
bar()
# $`Nov.`
# [1] 1 2 3 4
bar(F)
# $`Sep.`
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```